# Fractional linear transformations?

Tags: geometry, linear-fractional-transformation

Consider plane R2 as a complex plane. Consider the transformation $z -> \frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Which circles under this transformation will become lines?

I'm trying to understand how these transformations work and currently am extremely confused about how to work something like this. Any tips

Comment: Do you agree that for a circle to get mapped to a line, some point on the circle has to get mapped to the point at infinity?

Comment: Any circle that goes through $1$ will be sent to something that goes through $\infty$, so, a line. And if no point goes to infinity, the circle can't go to a line.

Comment: Could you explain why a circle going through 1 would get mapped to infinity? My knowledge as of right now is very beginner

Comment: Look at what happens to the denominator when $z=1$

Comment: The circle won't get mapped to infinity, but $1$ gets mapped to infinity, so the circle gets mapped to a line.

Answer (score 0):

A line in $w$-plane ($w\in\Bbb{C}$) is given by the equation
$$(a+bi)w+(a-bi)\overline{w}=c$$
where $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$, $a^2+b^2\neq 0$. Let $w=f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$. Then the pre-image of the line above under $f(z)$ is
$$(2a-c)x^2+(2a-c)y^2+2by+2cx-2a-c=0$$
which is a circle when $2a-c\neq 0$ and a line otherwise. It can be checked that it is passing through $1=(1,0)$.

Conversely, any circle or line passing through $1$ in $z$-plane is sent to a line because $f(1)=\infty.$ Or we can arrange the coefficients. For example, the circle $x^2+y^2-2x_0x-2y_0y+2x_0-1=0$ passing through $1$ in $z$-plane is sent to the line $(\frac{x_0-1}{2}+y_0i)w+(\frac{x_0-1}{2}-y_0i)\overline{w}=x_0$ in $w$-plane.